# Counting Rows based on Identifier - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a many to many relationship between two tables. `categories and products tables` and the pivot table is `category_product`.

In my category table, i have an attribute `no_of_products` which is to keep the number of products under that category and it is nullable (because, i create the category before adding the products under the category).

**How do i update the `no_of_products` after saving a product under a category**. This is what i have tried but i am getting confused.

**Do i have to count from the pivot table where i have the relations inserted?**

I am beginner with database and laravel.

**ProductsController**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product(array(
               'name'  => $request->get('name'),
            ));

                 $product->save();
                 $product->saveProduct($request->get('category'));  

                 $count_product = Product::count();               

             }
```

Comment: Don't store that count. You can use a join in the query to calculate the number of products in a category dynamically with a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Can i also use eloquent with the query builder?

Comment: Storing total records in a variable seems like a good idea because it prevents unnecessary queries in the database.
 
Bad:
`foreach ($ product-> count () as $ product) {// ...}`

Better:
`$ productsCount = $ product-> count; foreach ($ productsCount as $ product) {...}`

Comment: @MauricioRodrigues Not really, you can get the count as part of the query for the categories and cache the query response. Then you have all the data in one place and can flush it when it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store total products count in database. You can simply update `$withCount` property in your `App\Category` model like this:

```
protected $withCount = ['products'];
```

This will automatically give you total number of products for a category through a property `$category->products_count`

Comment: where from the `products_count` please?

Comment: Just simply set this property in your model file e.g. `app/Category.php`